# Change validation rules on the fly

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm working on a form that contains user data, specifically a phone number field. The phone number typically isn't required so the only validation rule in the model is the `usphone` rule. However, if the user is submitting this form, the phone number becomes necessary. I thought I'd be able to simply add a `validate` rule on the fly, set the model and call the `validates` method, but either I'm doing it wrong or it's not working the way I expected.

In my controller:

```
# Update a few validation rules that are specific to this context
$this->Proposal->Requestor->validate['phone_number']['notempty'] = array(
  'rule'       => 'notEmpty',
  'message'    => 'Please enter a phone number so can can contact you with any questions about the work.',
  'allowEmpty' => false,
  'required'   => true,
);

$validationErrors = array();
$this->Proposal->Requestor->set( $this->data['Requestor'] ); # $this->data['Requestor']['phone_number'] only (no other requestor data)
if( !$this->Proposal->Requestor->validates( array( 'fieldList' => array( 'phone_number' ) ) ) ) {
  $validationErrors['Requestor'] = $this->Proposal->Requestor->validationErrors;
}
```

No errors are reported, even if I leave the phone number field empty. In this case, the only information I'm requesting from the user is their phone number, so the rest of the `Requestor` data is empty, but I've tried merging in the rest of the user data and I get the same result. If I remove the `fieldList` option, I get an error on a different field, but still nothing on the empty phone number.

Any idea what I'm missing here? I've been monkeying around with this for hours now and I just haven't found the right answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being twofold:

1. I had existing rule on the `phone_number` field that forced the value to be a US phone number. That rule also set `allowEmpty` to `true` and `required` to `false`. I wanted to catch an empty value so I could display a particularly precise message.
2. I had to update the existing rule to flip the `allowEmpty` and `required` values and also add a new rule with its `last` value set to `true`.

The final change, added in my controller action looks like this:

```
$this->Proposal->Requestor->validate = Set::merge(
  $this->Proposal->Requestor->validate,
  array(
    'phone_number' => array(
      'notempty' => array(
        'rule'       => 'notEmpty',
        'message'    => 'Please enter a phone number so can can contact you with any questions about the work.',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'required'   => true,
        'last'       => true,
      ),
      'usphone' => array(
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'required'   => true,
      ),
    )
  )
);
```

I can't remember whether I verified that the change to the existing `usphone` rule was strictly necessary given the `last` value of the new rule, but this combination is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the Multivalidatable Behaviour - http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model